# catkin tools command not found

Tags: ros, pr2, catkin-tools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I installed catkin tools (http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) in one of the users for a PR2 (locally installed with --user) by following the instructions in http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html#installing-from-source.

The problem is when I try to run the catkin command as I get the following message:

`-bash: catkin: command not found`

If I try to use it like this:

`~/.local/bin/catkin`

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../.local/bin/catkin", line 5, in <module>

from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2707, in <module>

working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 686, in require

needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 584, in resolve

raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: osrf-pycommon>0.1.1
```

I'm not sure where to look at with this error....

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232381/catkin-tools-command-not-found/) by [TDTron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26070/tdtron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-04-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sood](https://answers.ros.org/users/26384/sood/) on 2016-04-20**:
try doing source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first issue is most likely caused by the fact that `~/.local/bin` is not in the user's `PATH` environment variable. When you do a non-user-specific `pip` install the executables will get put into `/usr/local/bin` which is likely on your path by default (the same is true with an apt-get install although it will likely be  in `/usr/bin`).

The second issue (where you provide full path to the executable) is because Python can't find modules that `catkin_tools` depends on. This is most likely because `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (and possibly `~/.local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`) are not on the user's `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. In global pip installs and apt-get installs, this would also not be an issue.

Try fixing those two environment variables for the user, and the issues should go away.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TDTron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26070/tdtron/) on 2016-04-27**:
Yeah, the ~/.local/bin was not in the PATH and the other issue was that there were some dependencies not installed. The installation process I followed then was different from the one they have now in their site (they included pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade)